# Do Apple Store Gift Cards Ever Expire?

Tags: apple-store

I have an Apple Store Gift Card that was found in a drawer from 2009 (8 years ago). The associated papers said it was for $150. The scratch-off material covering the PIN had never been removed.

When I checked the balance, the PIN and card # were recognized, but the site said the balance was $0. I checked the balance here: https://secure1.store.apple.com/shop/giftcard/balance

Do these cards ever expire?  If not, how did it lose its value if the PIN had never before been uncovered?

*Note: This is not an iTunes gift card. That's different.*

Additional information: This is an OLD card. It doesn't appear to be the type that can be recognized by scanning. It does have a bar code, but the bar code is not in a box like the new cards. It also has a magnetic stripe. I couldn't figure out how to enter it into Apple Wallet or Apple Store apps. The front of the card is blank silver with white apple logo. The gift card number is 16 digits and the PIN is 8 digits.

Comment: I'd say your best bet at this point would be to contact Apple directly, preferably at an Apple Store proper, if there is one nearby. They're likely the only ones that can help you with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen one expire. You can enter it in your wallet app if you have an iPhone and the balance will come down from Apple's servers. I suppose a call to the 800-MY-APPLE sales number could confirm the balance as well.

Comment: Same—I looked into this years ago and confirmed that they don't expire. I don't have that reference anymore, however.